# Must Appositives be in the Same Person?

Tags: grammar

Does formal English grammar require that appositives be in the same person?  For example,

> John, my friend, works at the diner.

Here both *John* and *friend* are in the third person.

However, what about a sentence such as this:

> I beg you, the reader, to give these writings a chance.

Here we have the third person *reader* in apposition to the second person *you*.  Is such a sentence outside the realm of formal grammar? Or is there no grammar rule requiring appositives to have identical persons?

Comment: No. Noun phrases do not agree in person. Indeed, appositives are virtually always third person, since they're referential. But they can be in apposition with a noun phrase of any person - first, second, or third.

Comment: This is perhaps a reflection on the fact that 'person' doesn't always  correspond 1-to-1 with who is really being addressed. When one says 'People should not use mobiles while they're driving' it's often a hedged form of 'You should not use a mobile while you're driving'. // Perhaps 'I beg you, reader, to give ...' is more felicitous (though not more acceptable).