# What is the grammar term for "John" in "I John want to eat."

Tags: grammar, subjects

Take this sentence, where *John* is clarifying himself.

> **I John** do hereby declare that I am hungry.

- **I** is the subject.
- What is **John**?

**John** takes the place of an [intensive reflexive pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/368839/315731), if the sentence read...

> **I *myself*** do hereby declare that I am hungry.

But **John** is not a pronoun. It is a proper noun at that.

So, is this an *intensive proper noun*? Is **John** then an *Intensive Subject*? What do we call "John" in this pattern?

Comment: Works like any appositive. I, the speaker, sayeth thus. You, Baby, are the best.

Comment: It's a noun phrase, all right. This construction is called an **Appositive** noun phrase. Both the subject NP and the appositive NP refer to the same thing (or person, as here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammar analysis: \[We\] \[two brothers\] are responsible for this act. \[We\] \[both\] are responsible for this act](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559482/grammar-analysis-we-two-brothers-are-responsible-for-this-act-we-both) Also [Must Appositives be in the Same Person?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376236/must-appositives-be-in-the-same-person)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please look at least at the first comment before recommending dups. The answer to that proposed dup is a "determinative". The answer to my question is "appositive". "Determinative" comments help to clarify, is useful, but it does not provide an answer.

Comment: [This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114017/correct-punctuation-with-two-nouns) is about "uncle Jack", which could also be considered a title, such as "Mr. Kipling", baring punctuation. My question couldn't possibly have that confusion.

Comment: @JesseSteeleיִשַׁי: John Lawler also says yours is a duplicate question about an "appositive" usage, so I think I'm in good company! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Alright, fair enough. Is there really an answer that provides this information? Should I move my answer somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not sure how meaningful it is to keep subdividing syntactic categories like this, bearing in mind that the actual underlying *language* isn't "specified by design" to fit into this somewhat arbitrary set of pigeonholes. I can see good arguments for saying that in a legal document, for example, *I, **John Smith,** do hereby declare...* is a "restrictive appositive" (distinguishing ***this*** "I" from everyone else's written depositions). But if John Smith uses those very same words to start addressing a meeting *in person*, it's just BillJ's "supplementary appositive".

Comment: ...I'm sure someone could make a case for saying (1) ***I, John Smith,** do not support this proposal* and (2) *...but **my brother, Jack Smith,** does support it*. are *different types of "appositive"*. But what's the point?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually needed it on Hermeneutics. We could argue that asking for grammar terms like this is off topic, if Linguistics wants them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers having terms to talk about how language is used can have implications when trying to understand the meaning. It really makes a difference there. "Usage", that way, wouldn't just be using it correctly, but understanding based on how it is used. That's where I was coming from.

Comment: Well, I guess you could ask for clarification on Linguistics. Unless I've missed something, it seems to me the possible difference between using ***I, John Smith*** in a legal document or as self-identification in person in a meeting, AND the difference between those and my example ***My brother, Jack Smith*** might exemplify the specific range of "sub-types" you're interested in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm at a loss here, because I know where both of you are coming from. I need discussion on Greek -> English translation; many of the grammar terms are the same, so asking just for the English terms is sufficient. If I went to Linguistics, they should probably tell me to ask here. But here, it's more technical than most people need. But, here is where the experts are who know the answer to my question.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I don't know much about ancient Greek orthography, but I'm pretty sure we don't meaningfully have access to the *real* (spoken) language they used. But I doubt they had written commas, and who's to say whether *The king **Agamemnon** had a brother **Menelaus*** would have had "pauses" before either of those names? From the perspective of a modern-day Anglophone, the presence / absence of those commas/pauses might be critical in assigning "linguistic sub-categories" to those "appositive" names. But at the end of the day, we might just be inappropriately comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My degree is in Greek, but not English, so I asked that part here. And yeah, going into the Greek is a can of worms, or wormy oranges and apples. My point is that the English details of terms really can matter with some fields that involve English. So, the details I’m asking for are relevant. Get me?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't get you. I never heard of "intensive reflexive pronoun" before now either, but quite frankly I think that's not a very good designation anyway. The Wikipedia author could at least have called it an ***intensifying** reflexive pronoun*, for consistency with the more general use of ***intensifier*** for a broad range of such usages. But ferreting around for precise technical terms to describe specific usages strikes me as a mug's game. Like Victorian grammarians desperately trying to shoehorn the elements of modern English into a categorisation system appropriate to Latin.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've explained why it has practical uses for some fields, including mine. That said, it is indeed just silly if one has no use, and can be harmful. We all have different things that matter and don't.

Answer (score 0):

**Restrictive Appositive**

This is called [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition):

> a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side so one element identifies the other in a different way

eg:

> ***My friend Alice Smith*** likes jelly beans.

- ***Alice Smith***: appositive phrase
- ***My friend***: phrase in apposition

Note the difference between [restrictive and non-restrictive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Restrictive_versus_non-restrictive):

**restrictive**: (provides essential information)

> I John do hereby declare that I am hungry.

**non-restrictive**: (parenthetical via commas, additional information)

> I, John, do hereby declare that I am hungry.

---

*Related and insightful, but not the same: [Grammar analysis: [We] [two brothers] are responsible for this act. [We] [both] are responsible for this act](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559482/grammar-analysis-we-two-brothers-are-responsible-for-this-act-we-both)*

Comment: 'I[,] John' cannot be a restrictive appositive since 'I' is totally identifying by itself. The comma in this case is added because 'I John' sounds unnatural in speech. //  'My friend John' **is** restrictive [/identifying, defining] since the particular friend is being identified. 'My friend, John' _is_ adding additional information but not intended as an identifying device.

Comment: I find Bradd Szonye's answer concise and satisfactory (apart from not stressing the usual  identification of non-defining appositives [and relatives] by adding the conventional commas). If you want to delve deeper, into whether the appositive can precede the 'other' NP/DP, or if there are 'non-synonymous appositives', you'll have to look elsewhere.

Comment: *I John...* — without the commas — would not be acceptable in formal written English.

Comment: Grammatically, appositives are always post-head modifiers . In your example, "My friend Alice Smith", "friend" is the head and the NP "Alice Smith" is the post-head modifier. There are no exceptions.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, in "I, John ...", "John" can only be a supplementary appositive, so a comma is, as you say, required

Comment: @WeatherVane This was what I was thinking, though: [Can we make markdown headers semantically correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271965/can-we-make-markdown-headers-semantically-correct) But, I think that it's not even working properly anyway. And, we both agree that it is ugly.

Comment: @WeatherVane And... I just found this about how using `# header` statements is [important for accessibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405008/accessibility-concerns-about-stack-overflow), *if used correctly*. Still, I don't like the huge newspaper header.

Comment: Hey, Jesse: Our expert mod -- @tchrist -- does (or use to do) the H1 all the time: e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579292/variant-of-english-pronunciation-in-the-uk/579303#579303 . But I have found myself having to compromise my HTML semantics in favor of the expected and accepted visual styles here.

Comment: @TinfoilHat IKR, it’s like a Catch 22. That’s why I just posted this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379157/405046